# Calling overrided method on Derived class casted from void ptr causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

Calling overrided method on Derived class casted from void ptr causes segmentation fault.
It doesn't if derive from concrete (non abstract) class.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct Base{
    virtual void base_method() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base{
    int x;
    void own_method(){
        printf("own %d", x);
    }
    void base_method() override{
        printf("base %d", x);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto * char_ptr = new char[500];
    void * void_ptr = char_ptr;
    auto derived_ptr = (Derived*)void_ptr;
    derived_ptr->x = 15;
    derived_ptr->own_method();
//    derived_ptr->base_method(); SEGMENTATION ERROR IF UNCOMMENT
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't run the constructor of `Derived`, so your code has UB. In case of ItaniumABI, your virtual table is not populated and thus you're likely jumping to an undefined address. If you'd like to use the `char` array / `void*` as the memory for `Derived`, you can do placement `new`:

```
#include <new>

auto derived_ptr = new(void_ptr)Derived;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know operator new has second parameter, thank you. 
Just for clarity it will require #include <new> header.

Comment: @ИванПоздняков You will also need to manually destroy the object you created with placement-new before you free the memory with `derived_ptr->~Derived();`.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting [`cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void *' to 'std::align_val_t' for 2nd argument`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96f42f28f923e8ea)?

Comment: @DavidG `#include <new>`